# Using an apply function to subset, match, and correlate multiple sets of variables in R

Tags: r

I'd like to use one of the apply functions to compactly subset, match, and correlate only the set of variables with the following strings: "hpi", "cpi", "eh".

Specifically, I'd like to apply all of the lines below the third comment (which only applies to "hip) below to each of the other strings.

Can you please advise?

MWE:

```
#Dataset 1
alias <- paste("v", seq( from = 1, to = 25 ), sep="" )
df1 = data.frame(replicate(25,sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df1) = alias

#Dataset 2
df2 = data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:1,25,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df2) = c("hpi","cpi","eh")
df2$alias = alias
df2$name = rep ( c("hpi housig", "cpi inflation", "eh econhealth", "unem unemployment", "inc personal income"), 5)

#I would like to use an apply function to do this to each of "hpi", "cpi", "eh"
df2$hpi = grepl("hpi", df2$name)
hpisub = df2[df2$hpi == 1, ]
hpisubvar = hpisub$alias
hpidf = df1[, hpisubvar]
corrhpi = cor(hpidf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*apply` functions apply function `FUN` to their first argument, so you need to write a function to be applied.

```
fun <- function(x){
    dfsub = df2[grepl(x, df2$name), ]
    cor(df1[, dfsub$alias])
}
```

Now we test it against your result, `corrhpi`.

```
identical(corrhpi, fun("hpi"))
[1] TRUE
```

And, finally, apply it to the vector you need.

```
vec <- c("hpi", "cpi", "eh")
result <- lapply(vec, fun)
names(result) <- vec
```